# How to create JSON webservice in ASP.NET with database connectivity?

Tags: asp.net, iphone, web-services, json, iphone-sdk-3.0

How to create a JSON webservice in ASP.NET that connect to MS SQL Database and update/delete values from the database?

This webservice will eventually be used to communicate with iPhone SDK.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

1) Make a data access layer of some sort.

```
Example: Linq to SQL, Entity Framework, SubSonic, nHibernate, ADO.Net
```

2) Create a web service (.asmx file) which calls your data access.

3) Make methods in the web service which return json seralized objects or what not.

```
 [WebMethod]
 public Item GetSingleItem()
 {
     return DataStore.FetchItem(); // return a single object
 }
```

4) Have a client which can send parameters to the web service and then consume the returned json. I'm thinking that your client on the iPhone will either be a native iPhone application or a web application run through the phones browser. Either way, this sounds like a neat idea.

Good luck, and hope this short list helps you out some.

Comment: Actually number two will totally depend on which data layer you're using. There are many examples of each option on the internet. Basically think of your web service as your business layer in a typical n-layer application.

Comment: Here is a link to some simple data access tutorials which may give you an idea of what I spoke about: http://www.dbtutorials.com/index.aspx